# Having trouble getting a POST request to work

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, http-post, bcrypt

I'm using Node, Express, & Mongoose trying to get this POST request to work using Postman but it keeps giving me the 500 status error. I also tried posting with just the username & instead of giving me the expected 400 status error it just gave me a 500 error again.

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const User = require('../models/userModel');

const registerUser = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        //get the username & password from the req.body
        const { username, password } = req.body;
        
        //check if the username is unique
        const uniqueCheck = await User.findOne(username);
        if (uniqueCheck) {
            res.status(403).json('Username already exists');
        }

        //hash password
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

        //check all fields are filled
        if (!username || !password) {
            res.status(400).json('Please fill in all fields')
        } else {
            //create user with username & password that is assigned to the hash version of it
            const user = await User.create(username, { password: hash }); 
            res.status(201).json(user);
        }        
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Problem registering user' });        
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding a console.error(error) statement in your catch block to better understand what is happening.

Comment: Good call. It said the findOne() needs an obj as parameter so I put username inside curly brackets but it's still giving me a different error now: node:internal/errors:465
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the clien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already I told you in the comment, you should ad a `console.error` statement in the catch block to better understand where is the problem.
Also, if the first `if` is matched, a response is sent to the client but the code execution will countinue, triyng to repliyng again to the client and giving you another error. You should return in the first `if` block to avoid it.
Check the following solution with comments on relevant edits

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const User = require('../models/userModel');

const registerUser = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        //get the username & password from the req.body
        const { username, password } = req.body;
        
        //check if the username is unique
        const uniqueCheck = await User.findOne(username);
        if (uniqueCheck) {
            return res.status(403).json('Username already exists'); // --> !!! add a return statement here
        }

        //hash password
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

        //check all fields are filled
        if (!username || !password) {
            res.status(400).json('Please fill in all fields')
        } else {
            //create user with username & password that is assigned to the hash version of it
            const user = await User.create(username, { password: hash }); 
            res.status(201).json(user);
        }        
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error) // --> !!! log errors here
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Problem registering user' });        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I figured it out. I did do the console.error & followed through putting my username into an obj at findOne the first time I commented back to you. I didn't know about needing a return in that one if statement but the issue was also my username wasn't in an obj for the create() method.